# Какая регулирка на любые буквы и цифры?

Tags: nginx

Имеется такая регулярка на nginx `^/(static)/\d+/(.+\.css)$` нужно убрать \d+ чтобы можно было использовать любые буквы и цифры, заместно \d+
Какая релагулярка, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `\w` - [Символьные классы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Символьные_классы_(наборы_символов))

Comment: спасибо большое